Ghost deployed on Cloud Run returns 503 error
Overview
I deployed Ghost using a Dockerfile on Cloud Run, but when I access the site, a 503 error occurs. Could you please advise me on how to check the details of the error?
Dockerfile
FROM ghost:latest
ENV database__client=sqlite3
ENV database__connection__filename=/var/lib/ghost/content/data/ghost.db
ENV PORT=2368
EXPOSE $PORT

What I've tried

I set PORT=2368 in the Dockerfile and deployed it to Cloud Run.
I checked the Cloud Run logs and found that a 503 error was recorded, but no detailed information was included.

Questions

Is there a way to check more detailed error information about the 503 error occurring in the Ghost application on Cloud Run?
Could you please provide troubleshooting steps to identify the cause of the 503 error and resolve it?


Additional Information

The following error is recorded in the Cloud Run logs:

[INFO] Creating table: recommendation_subscribe_events
[INFO] Model: Collection
[INFO] Model: Product
[INFO] Model: Newsletter
[INFO] Model: Tag
[INFO] Model: Permission
Cloud Run ReplaceService {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, authorizationInfo: […], methodName: google.cloud.run.v1.Services.ReplaceService, request: {…}, requestMetadata: {…}, resourceLocation: {…}, resourceName: namespaces/[namespace]/services/[service-name], respon…
[INFO] Ghost is running in production...
[INFO] Your site is now available on [service-url]
[INFO] Ctrl+C to shut down
[INFO] Ghost server started in 1.84s
Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "[container-name]" on port 2368.  


I'm using the latest stable version of Ghost (ghost:latest).
I'm using SQLite as the database.

If anyone has any knowledge or advice, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

where is the error? don't see no error.

Cause
In Cloud Run, when there are no requests, the container goes into a sleep state. When a new request comes in, the container starts up and processes the request.
The issue here was that the initial setup of Ghost takes time, and Cloud Run was terminating the container after processing the request, before the setup could complete.
Solution
By repeatedly reloading the page that was throwing the error, the setup of Ghost was able to complete, and the page started displaying normally.
This is because reloading sends a new request to Cloud Run, causing the container to restart. A few reloads provide enough computation time for the Ghost setup to complete.
